# Mega dropdown menu with fixed place content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've fiddled around with some mega menus, but I can't get them to use a fixed position for the drop down content. All of them shows the content like this:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/mega-dropdowns/

But I want it to show up like this *(no need for the fancy effects though)*:
simplifiedsafety.com/

I think I got it fixed, with the code HerrSerker posted

**Working code for others:**
http://jsfiddle.net/aT3nQ/embedded/result/
*This doesn't use js or jQuery though.*

Comment: What's your question?  Where's your code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `position:relative` on th `li`, add `position:relative` to the `ul` and give `position:absolute;left:0` to the `.sub`